# Closed form of $\mathscr{R}=\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^2x\,\ln\big(\sin^2(\tan x)\big)\,\,dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, closed-form

Inspired by Mr. [Olivier Oloa](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/118798/olivier-oloa) in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/867461/a-closed-form-for-int-0-pi-2-x3-ln32-cos-x-mathrmdx). Does the following integral admit a closed form?

> \begin{align}
> \mathscr{R}=\int_0^{\Large\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^2x\,\ln\big(\sin^2(\tan x)\big)\,\,dx
> \end{align}

It will be my last question before I take a long break from my activity on Mathematics StackExchange. So, please be nice. No more downvotes for no reason because this is ***a challenge problem***.

**Edit :**

I am also interested in knowing the numerical value of $\mathscr{R}$ to the precision of at least $50$ digits. If you use Mathematica to find its numerical value, please share your method & the code.

Comment: Using Matlab, the result seems to be $\mathscr{R}\approx -0.825490903211824$ at least that was the result of my computation (just as a first check, since this was already different from @Omran Kouba's result).

Comment: Guys, what are the downvotes for?

Comment: Please don't create a meta tag "challenge problem". Meta tags are very strongly discouraged in general - see http://math.stackexchange.com/help/tagging . There is a thread on meta about this one at http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/17275/630

Comment: Prof. @CarlMummert But WHY??? I have a privilege for doing so. Lots of questions on Math SE can be covered by using this tag. I think it is about time we have this tag on Math SE. Why don't you guys just leave me alone? Please don't bother my posts again. They're all legit. I didn't do something wrong here

Comment: @Anastasiya-Romanova Please try to keep a professional tone on this site. People on this site aren't out to get you.

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to
[make it take up less vertical space](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9686/290189) --
this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main
page is distributed evenly over the questions.
See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730)
for more information. Please take this into consideration for future
questions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Here's a slightly different approach. Using the power reduction formula and getting rid of the second exponent of the sine using the properties of the logarithm the integral becomes:

$$I=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} (1-\cos 2x) \log (\sin (\tan x))dx$$

Using the substitution $2x=u$ we have:

$$I = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^\pi (1-\cos u) \log\bigg(\sin \bigg(\tan \bigg(\frac{u}{2}\bigg)\bigg)\bigg)du$$

We have the integral ready for a Weierstrass substitution, after which it becomes:

$$I = \int_0^\infty\bigg(1-\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}\bigg) \log(\sin (t)) \frac{1}{1+t^2}dt$$

Or:

$$I = \int_0^\infty \frac{2t^2}{(1+t^2)^2} \log(\sin (t))dt$$

From now on I'll use $x$ again. The Fourier series of $\log (\sin x)$ is well known and it is:

$$\log(\sin x)= -\log 2 -\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos(2nx)}{n}$$

So the integral, exchanging integration and summation, becomes:

$$I=-2\log 2 \int_0^\infty \frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^2}dx-2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} \int_0^\infty \frac{x^2\cos(2nx)}{(1+x^2)^2}$$

These are both easy integrals from the point of view of residue calculus. The final result is:

$$I=-\frac{\pi \log 2}{2} -\frac{\pi}{2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{-2n}}{n}+\pi \sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-2n}$$

These sums can be evaluated using the geometric series and its integral.
So we have:

$$I=-\frac{\pi \log 2}{2}+\frac{\pi}{e^2-1}-\frac{\pi}{2}(2-\log(e^2-1))$$

Simplifying:

$$I=\frac{\pi}{2}\log \bigg( \frac{e^2-1}{2} \bigg) +\pi\bigg(\frac{2-e^2}{e^2-1}\bigg)$$

Comment: Hey!? Finally, you made it Marco, +1! But this is not Quora, you must use dollar sign `$` here :P

Comment: Finally had time to update my answer :P Anyway, where's the [math] tag I left? I don't see it.

EDIT: Oh, ok.

Comment: No need residue method for this part though
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos ax}{b^2+x^2}\,dx=\frac{\pi e^{-ab}}{2b}$$
and you can use its derivative w.r.t. $b$ to evaluate the latter integral. Nice answer anyway :)

Comment: I know you don't like it, but you'd be surprised of how comfortable it is :P

Comment: +1 Actually, one may apply the residue theorem directly to $\displaystyle \int^\infty_{-\infty}\frac{x^2\ln(1-e^{i2x})}{(1+x^2)^2}dx$ without the need to expand the integrand as a fourier series.

Comment: I didn't notice that! Still a bit new to the residue method :P

Comment: You only need to define $\log(\sin t)$ when  $\sin t$ is negative, this happens often for  $0<t$, and to justify the interchange of the integral sign and the series summation sign, especially when the series is not absolutely convergent.

Comment: You're absolutely right. While the first issue you mention is clearly not a problem, the second one is serious. Consider it just a formal procedure then.

Answer (score 21):

The answer is
$$
\mathscr{R}=\frac{\pi }{2}  \left(\log \left(\frac{e^2-1}{2} \right)-\frac{2
   \left(e^2-2\right)}{e^2-1}\right)
$$
As Kirill proved we have
$$\eqalign{
\mathscr{R}&=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{u^2}{(1+u^2)^2}\log(\sin^2u)du\cr
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^\pi\left(\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac{(u+k\pi)^2}{(1+(u+k\pi)^2)^2}\right)\log(\sin^2u)du
}
$$
Now, the function
$$
F(u)=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac{(u+k\pi)^2}{(1+(u+k\pi)^2)^2}
$$
is $\pi$-periodic and even function. It is not difficult to calculate its Fourier cosine coefficients $a_n$ such that
$$
F(u)=\frac{a_0}{2}+\sum_{n=1}a_n\cos(2n u)
$$
with,
$$a_n=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^\pi F(u)\cos(2n u)du
=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{u^2}{(1+u^2)^2}\cos(2n u)du= e^{-2 n} (1-2 n)$$
The last equality is obtained by a simple residue calculus.

On the other hand it is easy and well-known that
$$
\log(\sin^2u)=-2\log 2-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2}{n}\cos(2nu)
$$
So using Parseval's formula we get
$$
\mathscr{R}=\frac{\pi}{2}\left(- \log 2-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2}{n}e^{-2 n} (1-2 n)\right)
$$ 
and this simplifies easily to the announced closed form.$\qquad\square$

Answer (score 13):

Write $\tan x = u$ to get the integral
$$ \int_0^\infty \frac{u^2\,du}{ (1+u^2)^2} \log(\sin^2 u) $$
and split over periods of length $\pi$ by writing $u=\pi k+s$, $0<s<\pi$ so that the integral is
$$ 2\int_0^\pi \sum_{k\geq0} \frac{u^2}{(1+u^2)^2}\log\sin s\,ds, \qquad u = \pi k+s. $$
The sum can be done explicitly in terms of polygamma functions:
$$ \frac{1}{2\pi}\Im\psi\left(\frac{i+s}{\pi}\right) + \frac{1}{2\pi^2}\Re\psi_1\left(\frac{i+s}{\pi}\right), $$
so the integral is equal to
$$ \frac1\pi \int_0^\pi \log(\sin s)\left(\Im\psi\left(\frac{i+s}{\pi}\right) + \frac{1}{\pi}\Re\psi_1\left(\frac{i+s}{\pi}\right) \right)\,ds$$
which is numerically
$$ \begin{array}{rl}
-0.8254932940&1920795045&3494583393&8145490721&3051472153&0015143141\\
0263463153&8662518683&0960012709&2734877933&9171668805&2198716476\\
0581876961&2557665495&3473838059&8389072188&9187974995&4963384740\\
9429563810&6463831818&4148444098&6729534027&3239373746&3514130065&\ldots
\end{array} $$

Answer (score 2):

$$I = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin^2(x) \ln(\sin^2(\tan(x))) \, dx \\
= \underbrace{2 \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t^2}{(1 + t^2)^2} \ln(\sin(t)) \, dt}_{\text{Let } t = \tan(x)} \\$$
$$= 2 \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t^2}{(1 + t^2)^2} \left(-\ln(2) - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(2nt)}{n}\right) \, dt$$
$$= -2 \ln(2) \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t^2}{(1 + t^2)^2} \, dt - 2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t^2 \cos(2nt)}{(1 + t^2)^2} \, dt$$
$$= -\frac{\pi}{2} \ln(2) - \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} e^{-2n} \left(\pi - 2\pi n\right)
= -\frac{\pi}{2} \ln(2) + \frac{\pi}{e^2 - 1} - \frac{\pi}{2} \left(2 - \ln(e^2 - 1)\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

After the substitution $\tan{x}\mapsto x$, we get
\begin{align}
\mathscr{R}
=&\int^\infty_0\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^2}\ln(\sin^2{x})\ {\rm d}x\\
=&\Re\int^\infty_{-\infty}\frac{x^2\ln(1-e^{i2x})}{(1+x^2)^2}{\rm d}x-\ln{2}\underbrace{\int^\infty_{-\infty}\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^2}{\rm d}x}_{\frac{\pi}{2}}
\end{align}
Even though the function $\displaystyle f(z)=\frac{z^2\ln(1-e^{i2z})}{(1+z^2)^2}$ has infinitely many branch points at $z=n\pi$, once we close the contour along the upper half of $|R|$ and make semicircular bumps around the branch points, one may check (by letting $z=n\pi+
\epsilon e^{i\theta}$) that the contribution along the bumps vanishes. The integral along the big arc also tends to $0$. Hence
\begin{align}
\mathscr{R}
=&2\pi i{\rm Res}(f,i)-\frac{\pi}{2}\ln{2}\\
\end{align}
Using WolframAlpha to compute the residue and simplify terms,
$$\mathscr{R}=\frac{\pi}{e^2-1}-\pi-\frac{\pi}{2}\ln{2}+\frac{\pi}{2}\ln(e^2-1)$$